# Getting into python and trying to make some probability functions, ran into an error I do not understand

Tags: python, function, methods, compiler-errors

I am certain that I am righting my code syntactically well, however, it will not compile due to an error on line 10. I have no idea what the error is.

```
def fact(num): #A bit of recursion for a factorial
    if num == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return num * fact(num-1)

def comb(n, r): #Formula for probability combinations
    return (fact(n)/(fact(r)*fact(n-r))

def binom(t, k, p): #This is where the error occurs
    return (comb(t, k)*(p^k)*((1-p)**(t-k)))

print(binom(int(input("Enter n")), int(input("Enter r")), float(input("Enter p"))))
```

Since I had issues with repl.it in the past (which is what I am coding this on), I attempted going to other programs to compile the code, but my error persisted.

Comment: Well, what is the error?

Comment: That is what I am trying to find out, everything is telling me that there is an error, but the most the compiler says is "syntax error on line 10".

Comment: I think you are looking for the ** operator instead of ^ in line 11.
To elaborate further, ^ just sets all bits to zero, ** is the exponential function.

Comment: this line is an error:  `return num \* fact(num-1)`

Comment: `\*` is not allowed.  Also replace `^` with `**`

Comment: Also you have unbalanced parentheses on the line `return (fact(n)/(fact(r)*fact(n-r))`, which is what causes the error.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Please check for typos before asking here.

Comment: Yeah, the \* wasn't in the code I had before, I do not know what added it in, but I changed it back to just *. Also having ^ instead of ** seemed to not be the problem, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick scan, didn't go past this...

Look at the line following `def comb` and count open & close paren's...

```
return (fact(n)/(fact(r)\*fact(n-r))
       .    ^-^ .    ^-^      ^---^.
       .        ^                  ^
       .        `------------------'
       ^
       +------------------------------ missing closing paren.
```

..Otto